# c++ 11 lambda usage as delegate with std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback

I have a Button class which have an onClick std::function typed field and "setClickListener" method sets any lambda function to this std::function field as follows :

```
#include <functional>

class Button {

public:

void doSomething() {
   if(onClick) {
      onClick();
   }
}

typedef std::function<void()> OnClickListener;
OnClickListener onClick;

void setClickListener(OnClickListener onClickCallBack) {
   onClick = onClickCallBack;
}

};
```

In my application code, I am creating a lambda function and setting to onClick function of button as seen below :

```
#include "Button.h"

void onAnEventOccured() {
   button->setClickListener([this]()->void {
      // Do something
      memberFunction();
      anotherMemberFunction();
      // etc...
   });

}

void memberFunction() {
   // Do some work...
}

void anotherMemberFunction() {
   // Do some work...
}
```

Now, the critical section is that onAnEventOccured method called many times during the application's life cycle and the lambda function is set again and again. I am runnning on Visual Studio 2015 and putting debug trace point on the deconstructor of std::function class and can see it hits to tracepoint while setting setClickListener. I guess this is the deconstructor of lambda function which has been destroyed while leaving the scope of onAnEventOccured function and copy version of this lambda stored in Button instance as expected.

Am I correct on this? Is there any memory leak on this architecture?

Comment: Your two questions seems completely orthogonal. And as far as the trace point on destructor goes, it is probably of the temporary `std::function` object created while converting your lambda aka anonymous object to std::function object, not of the destructor of the anonymous object aka lambda.

Comment: There is no memory leak, the temporaries are destroyed.  I can not answer your other questions since your second fragment of code is invalid because you try to use `this` outside a member function.

If I understand what you try to do, you would have an `std::function<void()>` depending on an object that may be destroyed, perhaps you can have your function object be of type `std::function<void(Button &)>` so that you can explicitly pass in the button too.

Comment: Thanks for comments. @EdMaster, I know your concern and I guarantee that "this" pointer is valid, because it is my current screen in the application and rendering actively.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you call:

```
   button->setClickListener([this]()->void {
      // Do something
      memberFunction();
      anotherMemberFunction();
      // etc...
   });
```

in the constructor or during any other initialization method that you have on your Application code?

Also, your code could get an rvalue reference.

```
void setClickListener(OnClickListener&& callback);
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, but my listeners are changed during the lifecycle of the application according to handled events.